# Oozie trigger-file based coordinator. trigger file is not from hourly folders

Tags: oozie, eventtrigger, oozie-coordinator, crontrigger

I'm trying to create a coordinator with a dependency file - trigger file.
Frequency of my coordinator is 5 minutes. Timeout is 4 minutes.

My goal is that, the coordinator should execute the workflow only if the trigger file specified is created. In case trigger-file was not created coordinator should wait till the file is created and time-out at the end of 4th minute. The workflow deletes the trigger file once the workflow is triggered by coordinator. The trigger file comes whenever the source data is updated and so we have to run workflow again.

The trigger file may come multiple times a day, so I'm setting the coordinator frequency to 5 minutes. I have tried with the following code:

```
<coordinator-app name="transform_data_if_exists_coord" frequency="${freqMin}" start="${startDate}" end="${endDate}" timezone="${timeZone}" xmlns="uri:oozie:coordinator:0.1">
    <controls>
        <timeout>${timeOutMin}</timeout>
        <concurrency>${concurrencyCount}</concurrency>
    </controls>
    <datasets>
        <dataset name="input1" frequency="${coord:minutes(${freqMin})}" initial-instance="${startDate}" timezone="${timeZone}">
        <uri-template>maprfs:////idn/home/deploy/inputdata/file</uri-template>
        <done-flag>trigger</done-flag>
        </dataset>
   </datasets>

   <action>
      <workflow>
         <app-path>/idn/home/deploy/triggerEmail/triggerEmail_wf.xml</app-path>
      </workflow>
   </action>
</coordinator-app>
```

With below properties:

```
startDate=2016-01-26T18:20Z
endDate=2017-01-17T06:00Z
timeZone=UTC
freqMin=5
timeOutMin=4
concurrencyCount=1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an input event and property WaitForThisInputData in action

```
    <input-events>
            <data-in name="check_for_input" dataset="input1">
            <instance>${startTime2}</instance>
            </data-in>
     </input-events>

  <action>
      <workflow>
         <app-path>/idn/home/deploy/triggerEmail/triggerEmail_wf.xml</app-path>
<configuration>
                <property><name>WaitForThisInputData</name><value>${coord:dataIn('check_for_input')}</value></property>
</configuration>
      </workflow>
   </action
```

>

Comment: thank you for response.
but i'm facing below issue:
as the issue is long to fit in comment box. I've added it as answer. please have a look at it. please answer it if possible.

Answer (score 0):

though my workflow is getting kicked off only when trigger file is present.
sometimes double workflow is getting kickedoff with same parent coordinator instance. 
i.e. lets say if coordinator kicks off workflow at 25th instance of coordinator then work flow id contains parent as 
0001212-xxxxxxx-oozie-mapr-C@25

but i see two workflows getting kicked off with same parent coordinator instance which is not ideal. Both the jobs are being kicked off at same timestamp.
Am I missing property. I've set the concurrency of coordinator to 1. 
This issue is seen when trigger file comes after a significant gap in hours.